# Passing Firebase User Object To New Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, components, state

I'm new to React and Firebase and I'm trying get the user object that's populated after sign in/sign up to a new component so I can access it and create a database for each user, however I can't seem to access the this.state.user from another component. Here's my code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from './config/Fire';
import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
    }
  }

  // After this component renders, we will call on auth lister which will begin auth listener process
  componentDidMount(){
    this.authListener();
  }

  authListener() {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.user ? (<Home user={this.state.user}/>) : (<Login/>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and in my new component i have:

```
componentDidMount(){
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (this.props.user){
            console.log(this.props.user);
            // const userId = user.uid;
            // fire.database().ref(`users/${userId}`).set({
            //     username: '',
            //     age: ''
            // });
        } else {
            console.log('No user');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are listening for the user in componentDidMount of the App component, then you are passing that data into the home component in `<Home user={this.state.user}/>`

This means that you can refrence the user object inside the Home component as `this.props.user`.

You don't need to call the `onAuthStateChanged` handler again inside Home, you already did that in the App Component.

Hope that helps.